# Opengl GLSL render to texture

Tags: opengl, glsl

I'm trying to render to texture with OpenGL + GLSL shaders. For start I'm trying to fill every pixel of 30x30 texture with white color. I'm passing to vertex shader index from 0 to 899, representing each pixel of texture. Is this correct? 
Vertex shader:

```
flat in int index;

void main(void) {
gl_Position = vec4((index % 30) / 15 - 1, floor(index / 30) / 15 - 1, 0, 1); 
}
```

Fragment shader:

```
out vec4 color;


void main(void) {
color = vec4(1, 1, 1, 1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to render 900 vertices, with one vertex per pixel? Why are you doing that? What primitive type are you using. It would only make sense if you were using points, but then you would need some slight modification of the output coordinates to actually hit the fragment centers.

The usual way for this is to render just a quad (easily represented as a triangle strip with just 4 vertices) which is filling the whole framebuffer. To achieve this, you just need to setup the viewport to the full frambeuffer and render are quad from (-1,-1) to (1,1).

Note that in both approaches, you don't need vertex attributes. You could just use `gl_VertexID` (directly as replacement for `index` in your approach, or as aan index to a const array of 4 vertex coords for the quad).

Comment: I'm trying to render 900 vertices cause I want to be able to change color of every single pixel of texture and I'm using GL_POINTS.

Comment: @user1760770: welll, you can change the color of every single point with that quad apporach, too. the fragment shader is invoked for every single fragment. If you worry about how to get the data through to the fragment shader: textures are the standrad answer. You might even use a TBO to directly acces some buffer object from the FS.

Comment: I'm not quite sure how to get position of fragment at fragment shader.

Comment: @user1760770: you can get the window space positon of the fragment via [`gl_FragCoord`](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/manglsl/xhtml/gl_FragCoord.xml) builtin variable.

Comment: @user1760770: `gl_VertexID` is not supported in GLSL 110/120, it was added with OpenGL 3.0 (GLSL 130) / vertex instancing. However, I suspect this is a non-issue since the fragment shader uses `flat in` which is also not supported in GLSL 110. This is the reason `#version ...` is important: so we do not have to guess which features ***are*** and ***are not*** supposed to be supported :) Without `#version ...`, compilers and programmers are _supposed_ to assume `110` (OpenGL 2.0) was implied.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman: good point. I actually was ignoring the fact that he did not use a `#version` directive.  But `flat in` doesn't make sense in a _vertex_ shader, no matter what version.